# Ionic bar-header not centered when running on iOS device

Tags: ios, iphone, ionic-framework, vertical-alignment, text-alignment

I am building an app for Android and iOS using Ionic.
I use `bar-header` for titles in my views:

```
<ion-view view-title="Home" class="tab-home">
    <ion-content class="padding">
        <div class="bar bar-header bar-positive">
            <div class="h1 title">The European Experience</div>
        </div>
        <div class="bar bar-subheader bar-stable">
            <h2 class="title">Companion App</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="content has-header padding">
            ...
        </div>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

When displayed in my browser with `ionic serve -l`, the header is correctly displayed:

[image: ionic lab display]

When running on a real Android device, it works as well:
[image: run on Android]
But when I run the app on an iOS device (either physical or on Simulator), the title is not vertically centered:

[image: run on iPhone]
I tried adding CSS to explicitly specify `vertical-align` or `text-align`, but without success.

### What could explain this issue? And how can I center the title inside this header?

Answer (score 0):

This sort of problem is common depending on which Ios / Ionic versions you use ,
Did you try using the  Tag ?
[ion-header-bar](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionHeaderBar/)

Comment: I didn't try that, I'll tell you if it helps solving this issue!